# Flutter ios build failing: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am able to run the app in the simulator. All working fine. When I am trying to run `flutter build ios` or archive in xcode, its failing with below exception.

> Failed to build iOS app Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode):
> 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> /Users/xxxx/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.1.3/ios/Classes/messages.g.m:7:8
>
> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not
> found
> /Users/xxxx/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.1.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:4:8
>
> Encountered error while building for device.

Tried clearing pod folders, locks and clean installs. Nothing worked. Please help with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also downgrade the package version and then again delete the pod lock file, flutter clean, and pub get, then check it.